# How can create popup menu(window) as in the picture pyqt4

Tags: python, popup, pyqt4

**How can I create such a pop up window as shown in the image below? What libraries are available for the implementation of such a task?**

[image]

Important things are:

- The triangle at the top of the popup menu
- Shadows around the window
- The alignment of the window under the call button
- Python (pyqt4)

Comment: I think the image is from another OS not Windows OS.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860278/how-to-create-a-custom-gui-for-a-python-program